# How to make a simple web scraper and export the information into a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am wanting to make a web scraper for this website: https://www.ncaagamesim.com/college-basketball-predictions.asp

it has a  with  that has the information that I want. For each row, I want to get the odds number, and then subtract or add it from the average margin numbers in the prediction column based on the team. Then store that number somewhere with one of the team names.

This seems like a very simple web scraping program but I have no experience in this and would like some advice. Many tutorials use Python and Beautiful Soup so I think I will use that, but I'm not sure how I can store the information into something like a spreadsheet. Thanks!

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue better. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks --- Would be cool if you come with your coded approaches, also if you are new to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

So ya you're right you'd use beautiful soup to pull out the data. It's just a matter of putting it into a dataframe with `pandas` to get that into a spreadsheet

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.ncaagamesim.com/college-basketball-predictions.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table')

# Get column names
headers = table.find_all('th')
cols = [ x.text for x in headers ]

# Get all rows in table body
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

rows = []
# Grab the text of each td, and put into a rows list
for each in table_rows[1:]:
    odd_avail = True
    data = each.find_all('td')
    time = data[0].text.strip()
    try:
        matchup, odds = data[1].text.strip().split('\xa0')
        odd_margin = float(odds.split('by')[-1].strip())
    except:
        matchup = data[1].text.strip()
        odd_margin = '-'
        odd_avail = False
    odd_team_win = data[1].find_all('img')[-1]['title']
    
    
    sim_team_win = data[2].find('img')['title']
    sim_margin = float(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", data[2].text)[-1])
    
    if odd_avail == True:
        if odd_team_win == sim_team_win:
            diff = sim_margin - odd_margin
        else:
            diff = -1*odd_margin - sim_margin 
    else:
        diff = '-'
            
    
    
    
    row = {cols[0]:time, 'Matchup':matchup, 'Odds Winner':odd_team_win, 'Odds':odd_margin, 'Simulation Winner':sim_team_win, 'Simulation Margin':sim_margin, 'Diff':diff}
    rows.append(row)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)   
df.to_csv('odds.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
       Time                                     Matchup       Odds Winner  Odds Simulation Winner  Simulation Margin  Diff
0      2 PM                Buffalo  @ Western Michigan            Buffalo   9.5           Buffalo                7.3  -2.2
1      3 PM                 Akron  @ Northern Illinois              Akron     9             Akron                6.5  -2.5
2   4:30 PM             Kent State  @ Central Michigan         Kent State     6        Kent State                8.8   2.8
3      5 PM                       St. Katherine  @ UNLV              UNLV     -              UNLV               37.0     -
4   5:30 PM  Alabama State  @ Mississippi Valley State      Alabama State   6.5     Alabama State                5.9  -0.6
5      7 PM                Wisconsin (5) @ Michigan (4)          Michigan   3.5         Wisconsin                1.2  -4.7
6      7 PM       Eastern Illinois  @ SIU Edwardsville   Eastern Illinois     6  Eastern Illinois                7.4   1.4
7      7 PM                       Butler  @ St. John's         St. John's     2        St. John's                7.5   5.5
8      7 PM                 Saint Joseph's  @ Davidson           Davidson  12.5          Davidson               14.8   2.3
9      7 PM                        Ole Miss  @ Florida            Florida   3.5           Florida                8.5     5
10     7 PM                Ball State  @ Bowling Green      Bowling Green   7.5     Bowling Green                2.7  -4.8
11     7 PM                       Miami (Ohio)  @ Ohio               Ohio   8.5              Ohio                8.0  -0.5
12     7 PM                 Eastern Michigan  @ Toledo             Toledo    11            Toledo               10.6  -0.4
13     7 PM                    Miami  @ Boston College              Miami     3    Boston College                4.9  -7.9
14     7 PM                      Duke  @ Virginia Tech               Duke   1.5     Virginia Tech                8.2  -9.7
15  7:30 PM                            TCU  @ Oklahoma           Oklahoma     8          Oklahoma                8.3   0.3
16     8 PM               Kansas (22) @ Oklahoma State             Kansas   3.5            Kansas                0.7  -2.8
17  8:30 PM            Alcorn State  @ Grambling State    Grambling State   7.5      Alcorn State                2.8 -10.3
18     9 PM                            Syracuse  @ UNC                UNC   3.5               UNC                2.6  -0.9
19     9 PM                    Providence  @ Marquette          Marquette     3         Marquette                9.0     6
20     9 PM                        Alabama  @ Kentucky           Kentucky     2           Alabama                4.0    -6
21     9 PM                    UC Riverside  @ USC (12)               USC  14.5               USC               14.3  -0.2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @pumpkinchugger accept the solution if it met your needs.